# Getting "The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details." when sending a POST via the Chrome Postman plugin

Tags: json, post

I have been looking for a way to understand the root cause of the "The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details." problem in my particular case but none of the existing online solutions addresses the problem I am about to describe.

I need to send POST requests with JSON payload {"userName", "Adnan"} to an Azure-based web service which eventually retrieves some database GPS records in a HTTP response. My initial attempt to test this POST request worked fine via Fiddler (See image below) and Android OKHttp libraries.

[image]

However, when I tested the same request over my ultimate 3G platform, it gave the above-mentioned error. I managed to replicate the same error with the Chrome Postman plugin (See image below). It must be noted that even if I am sending the data **as a JSON payload**, the same error appears on the Postman plugin. Almost all the solutions to this problem online suggest on tweaking the webservice itself which should not be the case as it works fine with Fiddler and Android. So - my question is why the POST request shown above is not working with the Postman plugin. I believe if the problem is resolved on Postman, it would be resolved on my 3G embedded board as well. Thank you.

[image]